# How to pair computer with bluetooth hearing aids?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a Dell D630 with Bluetooth. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How do I pair a Bluetooth computer with Bluetooth hearing aids?

Comment: Did your hearing aids come with a manual? It might have some useful info.

Comment: Yes, what does the manual of your hearing aids say and what model are they? Do they require a certain Bluetooth version, protocol or codec? Are they really Bluetooth. I just spoke with a hearing impaired colleague an he said some of them require transmitters/receivers (e.g. are not really Bluetooth).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open System Settings by clicking the "gear" icon in the top-right corner of your screen:

   [image]
2. Under <kbd>Hardware</kbd>, you will see <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd>.
3. Open the <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> sub-menu by clicking on that. Search for devices and press the <kbd>Pair</kbd> button that should be on your hearing aids.
4. You will then see your hearing aids appear in the list of devices.
5. Click on them to pair.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the Ubuntu Software Center, type `bluetooth` into the searchbox in the upper right. This will show you a list of bluetooth-related software. The ones marked with a white check-mark in a green circle are already installed on your system.

You could also issue the commands `man rfkill;rfkill list` to make sure your Bluetooth hardware is not disabled.

Comment: This simply explains the process of discovering which bluetooth software is installed by default. It does not address the issue of "How can I pair these with my computer?"